# Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager not tracking all users from all locations

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are using GA with GTM to track an Ajax-based website.
We are tagging a pageview tag with some of the events (gtagChange in this case) to track the pageviews.

When I visit the page, my pageviews are not tracked in the real-time reports.
Anyway, I see some other users from other countries, I visit the same content than them to check if it is a failure of the tag in some pages, but I don't still see my visits. I have asked some colleagues in the same office and it happens the same.

I have tested the same with other Ajax-based site using also events to track the PV (https://lite.rwlabs.org/) and it tracks my visits in real-time.

I have seen with the GTM preview that the tag is firing and checked with the Google Tag Assistant that the tag is there. We don't have any filters for that GA property/view.

The site is https://www.redhum.org/ , the GTM code is GTM-TSLB63K and our GA code is UA-102874553-1

Any clue why this site and only this site is tracking only some of the visits?
Thanks/

Comment: Would it be possible that your local network is blocking data delivery to the GA endpoint?

On it's own GA is not blocking data based on the country

Comment: Solved... beginner mistake, I set up "cookieDomain" in GTM tag config as "default" and it should be "auto".